# Trying to send a document through a trigger

Tags: docusignapi, apex

I'm currently trying to automate the process of creating a docusign document and sending it by putting it into an apex trigger. I have managed to get the docusign api (via WSDL) into my org, and now I'm trying to add the code into the trigger to send out the document. Without pasting the entire code here, I've been following this [tutorial](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/accessing-docusign-api-from-salesforcecom-to-send-contracts-for-esignatures) and have gotten all of the required code into my trigger. Unfortunatly, when I run it, I get this error:

```
11:40:49.965 (12965647595)|FATAL_ERROR|System.VisualforceException: Getting content from within triggers is currently not supported.

Trigger.OpportunityTrigger: line 109, column 1
```

Does this mean that it's not possible to send a document in a trigger? The tutorial sends it through a controller, is that the only currently supported method?

Thank you for any help you can give me!

**EDIT:**
So I've gotten past that error (using a different [tutorial](https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=482443049344)), and am now getting this error.

```
System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService returned a SOAP Fault: This User lacks sufficient permissions. User does not have the permision to the CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates method faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx
```

This appears to be a problem with the Docusign user I am using for sending this document. I am currently using `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplates` to try and send a templated document out to up to 5 recipients.

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the error, but the tutorial you are using is several years old and uses the DocuSign SOAP API.   DocuSign now has a REST API which is probably easier to integrate (no wsdls etc) and it's more efficient (much smaller payloads).  You just make RESTful http requests to given URIs.  I'd recommend pursing that if you can't fix the above issue...

Comment: Have a look at the Developer Center for more info on REST:  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center

Comment: @Ergin I've managed to get around that error using a different tutorial, and am now encountering a different problem. I've edited my question to show the new error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What DocuSign account are you testing all of this with?  You can only use the DocuSign API with developer accounts, can you confirm you are using an account created through the DocuSign Developer Center?

Comment: @Ergin as far as I know, yes. It's for a Salesforce Sandbox.

Comment: You should confirm that by trying to log into your DocuSign developer sandbox through here:  demo.docusign.net.  Don't use the Login at the top of the page (that's for production), click the `Log in to sandbox` button in the middle of the page and try using your user credentials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up phoning into Docusign Support, and asking them about the issue. Turns out that the last error was caused by me trying to authenticate and sign into docusign with my userID not the AccountID (switched those around and the permission error went away).

Another error showed up related to not having roles setup properly in my template (fixed that by setting up the role), and now everything is working fine. I'm answering my own question to leave it as a reference to future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a call out from trigger
2. Then get the request from a rest method
3. Then continue to get the pagereference conten

You can find an example [here](http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/apex/send-email-with-generated-pdf-as-attachment-from-trigger/)